# Node.js POST data use

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to edit an application that I currently use to start a task if a certain pin is used.

What happens is my app sends a pin by `POST` command to the server. What I want is my Node.js app, when it sees this pin being used, to do an extra step. Below is the code I'm working on. I'm getting "error 500" when used.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
if((req.path === '/sessions' || req.path === '/sessions/')
    && (req.method === 'POST' && (pin === '1234')) {
      // do this step
    }
```

Comment: Where did you defined `pin` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read your 'pin' parameter directly.

You need to read from body with `req.body` that contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body.